# Error: Requiring external module babel-register

Tags: gulp, yeoman

sw_vers && node -e 'console.log(process.platform, process.versions)'
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.11.3
BuildVersion:   15D21
darwin { http_parser: '2.6.0',
  node: '5.2.0',
  v8: '4.6.85.31',
  uv: '1.7.5',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '47',
  openssl: '1.0.2e' }

node -v
v5.2.0

gulp -v
Requiring external module babel-register
CLI version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1

Getting error when running gulp serve, I've fixed this before by removing the entire webapp repo from local. Any and all help/advice appreciated, also please forgive if I've not formatted this issue as correctly as possible(first issue ever opened). Would like to resolve this without having to do this. gulp serve throws the following:

Running yeoman generator "Webapp", I'm getting an error when running gulp serve. Here are the following versions for a better background :

```
 sw_vers && node -e 'console.log(process.platform, process.versions)'
 ProductName:    Mac OS X
 ProductVersion: 10.11.3
 BuildVersion:   15D21
 darwin { http_parser: '2.6.0',
  node: '5.2.0',
  v8: '4.6.85.31',
  uv: '1.7.5',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '47',
  openssl: '1.0.2e' }


node -v
v5.2.0

gulp -v
Requiring external module babel-register
CLI version 3.9.1
Local version 3.9.1
Finally the gulp serve error:

gulp serve
Requiring external module babel-register
\node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:372
  throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + JSON.stringify(val) + "         relative to directory " + JSON.stringify(dirname));
```

Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be, any suggestions?

Here's what I've tried:

```
npm uninstall gulp 
npm install gulp 
//with global flag and not
npm install --save-dev gulp 
//installing babel-register manually w/wo global flag and --save-dev
npm install babel-register
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with running a custom project that was originally created using the [Yeoman Webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) and found a solution that worked for me. A bit of context... the project was running fine on my Windows 7 machine and when I tried to move it over to my Mac OSX machine I received the exact same error. What I found works is creating a new Yeoman Web App project and drag & dropping the exact **node-modules** folder structure over to your existing project. Most likely than not, there is a dev dependency that your machine is not reading and fetching accurately, in this case, the **babel-register** module which is contained within this **node-modules** folder.

If possible for you to do, it's also worth comparing the versions of node, npm, gulp, gulp cli with your previous working version and the version you are having trouble loading when running `gulp serve` to see if they match.